# Nested Field To create a new belongs_to record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I want to create a set of fields to create a new location in my `activties/_form.html.erb`

Once i have the form working, I'm planning on showing the form when clicking an **add another location** button or an extra option in the select location selectbox.

The story so far:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :location do |builder| %>
<%= render 'location_fields', :f => builder %>
<%= builder.hidden_field :provider_id, :value => @provider.id %>
<% end %>
```

**activity.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name, :price, :location, :location_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
```

The issue is, this all works a bit too well.  When you edit an activity record, the location fields are pre-populated with the associated location record.

How should i create a blank form so a new location is always created and associated with the activity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "New" location that does not have existing data. This will then be used by this form.

For example:
In your controller

```
@new_location = Location.new
```

You can then call the partial with this location object.

The location you are seeing in the field is probably the one that is already related to the activity. It depends on what you have in your controller.

You can also try nested attributes:

```
@activity.location.build
```

And then in your view do:

```
<%= f.fields_for :location do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.label :name %><br/>
  <%= builder.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ah, yes i tried that. and then in view: <%= f.fields_for @new_location  do |builder| %>  but i get Location(#2192237980) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Comment: I get a method not found using @activity.location.build in the controller.  How would that work for records that already have a location set?  wouldn't it reset it?